# Предложения в уведомлениях заканчивать точкой или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, дизайн, уведомления

Иногда без точки в конце:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иногда с точкой:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помню, где-то уже это обсуждали. К чему в итоге пришли? Если не было консенсуса, то давайте сейчас решим, чтоб в одном стиле были все уведомления.

Comment: надо обязательно добавить тег `перфекционизм`